# Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 24, column 1 (byte 528) after "}

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am able to run logstash as:

```
bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/config.json
```

but running logstash as a service

```
sudo service logstash start
```

is giving me the following error:

```
... Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 24, column 1 (byte 528) after "}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here? Configtest also says the config file is fine.

```
bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/config.json --configtest
Configuration OK
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `
input {
 file {
  path => "/var/log/test.log"
 }
}

filter {
   multiline {
      pattern => "^(%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601})"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
   }
   grok {
      match => { "message" => "(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:pid}%{SPACE}---%{SPACE}%{SYSLOG5424SD:threadname}%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:classname}%{SPACE}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}" }
   }
}

output{
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["10.25.48.161:9200", "10.25.46.96:9200"]
 }
}
`
Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 24, column 1 (byte 506) after "}

Comment: there are 22 lines only in the config file.. I don't think logstash is reading /etc/logstash/conf.d/config.json... how to confirm?

Comment: It combines all the files in conf.d together.  Try 'cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/* > /tmp/foo' and looking in there.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I placed a sample test log file to check the setup. It's working now. Thanks a lot Alain.

Comment: great; converted to answer then.

Comment: Nothing says "Thanks a lot" better than accepting their answer :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When logstash runs, it combines all the files in your config directory into one file.  When there's an error, you're getting line and position information into *that* merged config.

Try:

```
cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/* > /tmp/total.conf
```

and then look at line 24 or 25 there.

Comment: +1 what a helpful answer. Turns out that I had another file in the same directory which introduced unwanted chars to my configuration file. Much appreciated @AlainCollins

Answer (score 1):

FYI mine complains about line about line 163 and my combined files don't get that far.

Answer (score 0):

Here someone had left an ~.vimrc file in the conf.d directory, which was then appended to the big configuration file.

--configtest probably ignores the file, but reading configs did not.